# django - перебор и вывод субкатегорий

Tags: python, django

нужно перебрать и вывести в шаблоне все субкатегории, привязанные к конкретной категории. а дальше при клике на субкатегорию выводить все услуги связанные с ней. сейчас у меня успешно выводятся главные категории и по ним фильтруются услуги. но нужна фильтрация именно по субкатегориям. то есть категория > субкатегория > услуги.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Category, Service

def service_list(request, category_slug=None):
    services = Service.objects.filter(available=True)
    main_categories = Category.objects.filter(parent_category=None)
    sub_category = None
    
    if category_slug:
        sub_category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_slug)

        if sub_category.children.exists():
            categories = [sub_category] + list(sub_category.children.all())
            services = services.filter(category__in=categories)
        else: 
            services = services.filter(category=sub_category)

    return render(request, 
                  'main/list.html',
                  {'sub_category': sub_category,
                   'main_categories': main_categories,
                   'services': services})
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, db_index=True, unique=True)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = (['name',])
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        if self.parent_category:
            return reverse('main:service_list_by_category', args=[self.parent_category.slug, self.slug])
        return reverse('main:service_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])


class Service(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='services')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    preparation = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = (['name',])
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'))
        verbose_name = 'Услуга'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Услуги'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

list.html:

```html
{% extends 'layout/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            {% for category in main_categories %}
                <a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            {% for subcategory in category.sub_category_set.all %}
                <a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ subcategory.name }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px">
        {% for service in services %}
            <h6>{{ service.name }}</h6>
            <p>{{ service.description }}</p>
            <p>{{ service.price }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.service_list, name='service_list'), 
    path('<category_slug>/', views.service_list, name='service_list_by_category'),

]
```

Comment: {% for subcategory in sub_category.children.all %}
    <a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ subcategory.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}

- перебирает субкатегории. но при клике на {{ subcategory.name }} не фильтрует услуги, связанные с этой субкатегорией ((( помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!